# Can't see the evaluation of a simple equation of a serie.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can't see it directly how equation 1 to 3 became equal to equation 4.

Let n be the size of the array. First, we must find the smallest of n numbers. To
achieve that, we must visit n array elements. Then we swap the elements, which takes
two visits. (You may argue that there is a certain probability that we don’t need to
swap the values. That is true, and one can refine the computation to reflect that obser-
vation. As we will soon see, doing so would not affect the overall conclusion.) In the
next step, we need to visit only $n-1$ elements to find the minimum. In the following
step, $n-2$ elements are visited to find the minimum. The last step visits two elements
to find the minimum. Each step requires two visits to swap the elements. Therefore,
the total number of visits is

$(Equation 1)$ $ n + 2 + ( n − 1 ) + 2 + ... + 2 + 2$

$(Equation 2)$ $= n + ( n − 1 ) + ... + 2 + ( n − 1 ) ⋅ 2$

$(Equation 3)$ $= 2 + ... + ( n − 1 ) + n + ( n − 1 ) ⋅ 2$

$(Equation 4)$ $=\frac{n ( n + 1 )}2− 1 + ( n − 1 ) ⋅ 2$

Comment: You should re-write your question. In the first equation, it is unclear how many times $2$ is repeated. If possible, use the $\Sigma$ notation instead.

Comment: @jibounet    that was given in the book as it is. Actually i don't know how many times the 2 is repeated. I have add some text which was given. maybe helps.